# How to write Unicodes in Java (editors)

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I was reading the [Google Java Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s2.1-file-name) and came across this:

```
String unitAbbrev = "μs";                               Best: perfectly clear even without a comment.
String unitAbbrev = "\u03bcs"; // "μs"                  Allowed, but there's no reason to do this.
String unitAbbrev = "\u03bcs"; // Greek letter mu, "s"  Allowed, but awkward and prone to mistakes.
String unitAbbrev = "\u03bcs";                          Poor: the reader has no idea what this is.
```

I understand how to type "\u03bcs" in java editors such as eclipse, but how exactly do I type "μ"???

Copy and paste from internet source?

Please enlighten me....

**EDIT**: Especially say, I want to type a sentence in Greek letters, it would be kinda dumb to use "\u03bcs" <- this way, but copy/paste from internet sources seem to be too much work...

Comment: AltGr+m,u in the keyboard layout [I use](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/win/eurokb.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the Greek language to your OS

Answer (score 0):

At least on my windows 7, finnish keyboard layout, µ is bound to Alt Gr + m.
On different flavours of linux, it might differ a bit, but try something along the lines of ctrl + shift + (unicode) + enter.

Generally speaking though, you need to copy & paste them, learn the unicode sequence by heart, or learn to use greek keyboard..

Answer (score 0):

In my projects - and in increasingly more other projects -, UTF-8 is the standard encoding for both editor and java compiler. So there "µs" would be used.

In effect even for non-english code (business terms etcetera), using private members with accented letters improves readability.

If using a build infrastructure like **maven** the used encoding is formally specified.

The only drawback is that fonts not often encompass the entire Unicode range. Under Linux however there is font substitution for missing Unicode blocks. That especially for Asian scripts. The `µ` is however quite unproblematic.

That said, still there are some uses, like for control characters or hard space, `\u00a0`.